# execute an specific method of the instances in a list in python

Tags: python, methods

I would like to know if there's a function similar to `map` but working for methods of an instance. To make it clear, I know that `map` works as:

```
map( function_name , elements )
# is the same thing as:
[ function_name( element ) for element in elements ]
```

and now I'm looking for some kind of `map2` that does:

```
map2( elements , method_name )
# doing the same as:
[ element.method_name() for element in elements ]
```

which I tried to create by myself doing:

```
def map2( elements , method_name ):
    return [ element.method_name() for element in elements ]
```

but it doesn't work, python says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'method_name' is not defined
```

even though I'm sure the classes of the elements I'm working with have this method defined.

Does anyone knows how could I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`operator.methodcaller()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) will give you a function that you can use for this.

```
map(operator.methodcaller('method_name'), sequence)
```

Comment: Thank you! Just adding that one might `import operator` before

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lambda` expression. For example

```
a = ["Abc", "ddEEf", "gHI"]
print map(lambda x:x.lower(), a)
```

You will find that all elements of `a` have been turned into lower case.